# How to get all documents from a nested firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

A person has logged in the app. This person has some orders and these orders are split up in detailed overview list. Unfortunately is this list on the output empty. How can I get the values of the orders in the detailed overview list?

My firebase looks like this:
Collection: Users -> Document user id -> Collection bestellungen -> Document bestellungen id -> Collection geasmtbestellungen.

I want all documents from the gesamtbestellung. I have the current used id and the id of the collection bestellungen

```
public void getGesamtbestellung(int bestellnr) {
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("bestellungen").document().collection("gesamtbestellungen").whereEqualTo("bestellnummer",61)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        ArrayList<Bestellung> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bestellungen wurden gefunden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            //Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Bestellung best = document.toObject(Bestellung.class);
                            System.out.println("-------------------->" + best.toString());
                            list.add(best);
                        }
                        //System.out.println(list.get(0).toString());

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bestellungen wurden gefunden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Es ist ein Fehler beim Abrufen der Bestellungen aufgetreten: " + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query:

```js
db
    .collection("users")
    .document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .collection("bestellungen")
    .document()                             // note the missing document ID here
    .collection("gesamtbestellungen")
    .whereEqualTo("bestellnummer",61)
```

Note that you haven't identified a document under "bestellungen".  Passing no arguments to `document()` will generate a document reference with a random ID, which will almost certainly guarantee that you find nothing.

If you are trying to query subcollection under a specific document, you will have to provide the ID of that document.  There are no wildcards in query paths.

If you are trying to query against **all** of the documents in **all** of the subcollections called "gesamtbestellungen", then you will instead need a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: Thanks forr the answer! How could I get the document id of all documents with bestellnummer 61?

Comment: Did you click the link to read about collection group queries?